# How to import input variable from another file without repeated running this input function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, import

My master.py asks for participant name and then run other .py files that use this name:

**master.py**:

```
participant = str(input("Participant's name: "))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, subprocess
    cDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    files = ['antisaccade','change_detection','digit_span']
    for f in files:
        wDir = cDir+ '/' + f
        subprocess.run(["python", f+'.py'], cwd=wDir)
```

For example, **digit_span.py**:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))
from master import participant
filename = u'data/%s_%s_%s' % participant
```

So each time files are run, they cyclically call line with input:

```
participant = str(input("Participant's name: "))
```

But I need to ask for participant's name only once and then send it to other files.

If I put `input()` inside `if`, I get the

> ImportError: cannot import name 'participant'

Could someone explain how to solve this, please?

Comment: Instead of calling input function every time, save all names to a file and read it from that file.

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer its a script for cognitive experiment, so we never know who is the next participant. And I'd like to make process as simple as possible for experimenter, without extra actions like open file, write name, close, then run script..

Comment: Then you can pass the name as arugement to those scripts which you are calling later in the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **master.py** ask for name and run scripts **.py** which are in the list, what you can do is to pass the name as arguement.

Just like this:

**master.py**

```
participant = list([str(input("Participant's name: "))])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, subprocess
    cDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    files = ['slave']
    for f in files:
        wDir = cDir+ '/' + f
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "{0}.py".format(wDir)]+participant)
```

**slave.py**

```
import sys

with open("check.txt".format(sys.argv[1]),'w') as f:
    f.write("{0} participant".format(sys.argv[1]))
```

**master.py** will run **slave.py** along with the arguments.

To test the result, it will generate a file **check.txt** with participant's name in it which means that **master.py** is passing the name to the (**slave.py**)script.

Comment: thank you very much for help, now it works! Also I added process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "{0}.py".format(wDir)]+participant) process.wait() to make to wait the end of subprocess